# InputTextarea of prime faces not applying the maxlength

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `<p:InputTextarea />` tag like this

```
<p:inputTextarea id="description" required="false"
    label="description" maxlength="255" tabindex="3"
    rendered="#{basicSetupController.description}" validatorMessage="Maximum allowable length for description is 255"
    value="#{basicSetupController.basicSetupBean.description}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="255" />
</p:inputTextarea>
```

I am facing problems that prime faces is not limiting the user after having entered 255 characters.  The user enters as many characters as he/she wants.  Although the validateLength tag works fine but the demand of the client is that the user should not be able to enter more than 255 characters.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Which PF version? Works just outright for me on PF 3.0 Final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue has been resolved by the primefaces in the later releases. No need for  `<f:validateLength>`. Primefaces itself restricts the user to type more than the maxLength set

```
<p:inputTextarea id="details" maxlength="20">
            </p:inputTextarea>
```

works pretty well now.

Comment: Are you sure the maxlength is enforced server side? Meaning you cannot tamper with it client side?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function validate()
     {
       var x=document.getElementById("form:text").value;
       if(x.length > 255) {
          document.getElementById("form:text").value=x.substring(0,255);
       }

     }
</script>

 <h:form id="form">

         <h:inputText id="text" onkeyup="validate()" />

 </h:form>
```